# Forward-declaring template pointer

Tags: c++, templates

Do I really need three statements, i.e. like this

```
class A;
template<class _T> class B;
typedef B<A> C;
```

to forward-declare a pointer of template type `C`, like so:

```
C* c = 0;
```

I was hoping to be able to conceal the classes `A` and `B` in my forward-declaration, is that even possible?

Comment: And litb's 2-line method is a bit less straightforward.

Comment: @rlbond, moved to an answer and removed the 2-line scary-code

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Although not exactly the same, you could do this instead:

```
class C;
C* c = 0;
```

and then later, in the implementation file, after the header files for "A" and "B" have been included, define "C" like this:

```
class C : public B<A> {};
```

Using inheritance instead of a typedef should work if you only need to use the default constructor of B<A>.

Comment: EDIT: You don't need to forward declare "A" and "B" in the implementation file. Header files should be included.

Answer (score 3):

Yes you need. Note that all three lines do different things. The first declares a class. The second declares a template, and the third declares a typedef-name. In declaring the typedef-name, you can use an elaborated type specifier like "class A" to name the class without having its name in scope (with some nasty pitfalls included) - but you cannot further collapse the template declaration with the typedef declaration.

I would not worry about the three lines. If it's necessary, i would just write them out :)

Comment: I had hoped that, since I'm only using it for a private pointer, there would be a nice way to only reserve the necessary space without having to reveal the underlying details.

Comment: What do you mean? Can you please write code into the question how you wish it should look and how it looks now? I think we can then better understand it

Answer (score 1):

I don't really understand your question, but code like this:

```
template<class _T> class B;
```

is illegal. C++ reserves names begining with an underscore 
and an uppercase letter for the compiler & library implementation - you are not allowed to use them  in your own code.